# is there any way to have an encrypted sqlite database?

Tags: android

I have a sqlite database in my app which I don't like others to extract and use it without my permission.

If this is impossible, can I use another DMS (instead of sqlite) which has this possibility?

Comment: You can use [SQLCipher](http://sqlcipher.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any way to have an encrypted sqlite database?

You can help the *user* defend the *user's* data via something like SQLCipher for Android.

> I have a sqlite database in my app which I don't like others to extract and use it without my permission.

An encrypted database, whether SQLCipher or otherwise, will not block access to the data. Your passphrase for the encryption will have to be in the app. That passphrase can be found by reverse-engineering your app. While you can use tools like DexGuard to try to make reverse-engineering more difficult, if somebody is interested in the data, they can get to it.

Comment: SQLCipher is free only on android which means all the data has to be added on the device,while I want to ship a prepared database of which all the data is collected on a desktop machine .

Comment: @Joseph_Marzbani: SQLCipher is free on all platforms. *Binaries* are only free on Android. You can compile SQLCipher from source for other platforms.

Comment: two more things: do you know any link or something from  which I can download those binaries for Win32?

and do you think this library could affect performance/speed negatively?

Comment: @Joseph_Marzbani: No, I do not know where you can download binaries for Win32. Performance is not a big problem on decent hardware, as the CPU overhead for the crypto is dwarfed by the I/O time. Generally speaking, it will make unoptimized database access incrementally worse.